# Determining if an Int Fits into a Short in C using Bitwise Operators

Tags: c, binary, int, bit-manipulation

I am tasked with making a function that returns whether or not an int x fits into a short in C (return 1 if it does, 0 otherwise). This would normally be a fairly simple solution, but I'm constrained to using only the following bitwise operators:! ~ & ^ | + << >>.

Here are some more rules:

- I am only allowed to use a maximum of 8 of these operators.
- No external libraries are to be included.
- I'm not allowed to use any conditional statements (so no ifs, whiles,
  etc).
- The only variables I can work with are those of type int and I cannot
  define constants like 0x0000ffff. However, I can use 0x0and 0xff.
- It is safe to assume ints are 32 bits and shorts are 16 bits.

I understand the basic functionalities of these operators, but am confused on the logic of implementation. Any ideas?

Comment: Good point, I forgot to mention that. It is safe to assume that ints are 32 bits, shorts are 16 bits and 2's complement is ok to use. How would I go about proving the uppers 17 bits of the `int` are either all 1 or 0?

Comment: To be clear, do you specifically mean a function that can tell if an integer is in the range of a short?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Supposing two’s complement, arithmetic right-shift, left-shift that discards overflowing bits, and 32-bit `int`, then:

```
x<<16>>16 ^ x
```

is zero if and only if `x` fits in a 16-bit `short`.

Since we are asked to return zero for does-not-fit and one for does-fit, we can return:

```
! (x<<16>>16 ^ x)
```

Proof:

If `x` fits in a `short`, then `x`•2<sup>16</sup> fits in an `int`, so `x<<16` produces that with no overflow, and `x<<16>>16` restores `x` (since arithmetic shift right that only removes zeros is effectively a division with no remainder), after which `x ^ x` is zero.

If `x` exceeds a short, then `x<<16` overflows (which we assume results in discarding the high bits). Furthermore, its value is one of the values produced by `y<<16` for some `y` that is a short. Then `x<<16>>16` must produce the same value as `y<<16>>16`, which is `y`, which differs from `x`, and therefore `x<<16>>16 ^ x` cannot be zero.

Comment: That's a great explanation, your logic is very clear and easily understandable. You're also right in saying that I've forgotten to specify what I need to return. If `int x` can fit into the short, we will return 1. Otherwise, return 0. How could I accomplish this without conditionals?

Comment: @vastImmortalSuns: Updated.

Comment: Wouldn't undefined behavior result if `x<<16` overflows given the constraint of only being allowed to use `int`? (that is unclear in the question - perhaps that includes unsigned int)

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin: I will edit the answer to make it more explicit, but it assumes the behavior wraps in a two’s complement representation. These bit-level exercises typically assume things like that. The goal of these exercises is not to teach formal C semantics but to teach basic notions about bits, two’s complement, amd so on.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming 2 complements, your original idea to test that all leading but 15 bits are all 0 or all 1 does work.

```
11111111 11111111 1xxxxxxx xxxxxxxx /* for negative 16 bits int */
00000000 00000000 0xxxxxxx xxxxxxxx /* for positive 16 bits int */
```

Assuming arithmetic right shift, you can shift right by 15 to eliminate the unknown bits, then only 1s or 0s will remain (if it fits on 15 bits)

Thus `x>>15` should then be either 0 or -1.
If it is 0, then !(x>>15) is true.
If it is -1, then !(~(x>>15)) is true.
You can thus test `!(x>>15) | !(~(x>>15))`
Or you can also write it like that: `!(x>>15) | !(~x>>15)`

Note that above expressions don't assume 32bits x, and would also work for testing if an int64 would fit into an int16...

There are many other ways...
Since you can also use +, `(x>>15)+1` is 0 or 1.
You can then clear the last bit with: `((x>>15)+1)>>1`.
`x` does fit in 16bits int if above expression is all 0 (false), thus you want:

```
! (((x>>15)+1)>>1)
```

Up to you to find more expressions...